# How to run Unix commands in python installed on a windows machine?

Tags: python, windows, shell, unix

I tried using some Unix command using the subprocess module on my Python interpreter installed on a windows 7 OS. However, it errors out saying command not found. It does recognize Windows commands though. Can I somehow use Unix commands in here too?

Thanks,
Vishal

Comment: >>> subprocess.call('pwd',shell=True)
'pwd' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
1

Comment: >>> subprocess.call('dir',shell=True)
 Volume in drive C is OSDisk
 Volume Serial Number is 90CF-90DB

 Directory of C:\Python34

11/14/2014  11:38 AM    <DIR>          .
11/14/2014  11:38 AM    <DIR>          ..
11/14/2014  11:38 AM    <DIR>          DLLs
11/14/2014  11:38 AM    <DIR>          Doc
11/14/2014  11:38 AM    <DIR>          include
11/14/2014  11:38 AM    <DIR>          Lib
...

Comment: You can't run "linux" commands on Windows. Just like you can call Windows commands on linux. You'll need to add something in the middle. For instance cygwin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't run a command that's not there. There are multiple options for obtaining POSIX/GNU commands for Windows, including [Git Bash](http://www.git-scm.com), [MSYS/MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/), [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/), etc.

Comment: Allright, thanks. I thought there could be a bash module in python itself I could use. Doesn't look like it. Thanks anyways

Comment: @user3399273 no problem. If my answer helped solve your problem, please consider indicating that by clicking the check mark next to the answer. It marks your question as resolved, and generates reputation points for both of us. See [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install Unix Bash for Windows, but not sure if it works correctly ... Better solution is install or virtualize some Linux distribution.